# method parameter aspectj is not working spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, aspectj

I have created an annotation with name Validation and inject on method parameter and I have been using aspect before invocation to validate my object. It is not working

Annotation code

```
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Validation {}
```

Aop Code

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class ValidatorAOP {
    @Before("valditionAnnotation()")
    public void validate(final JoinPoint jp) throws Throwable {
        Validator object = (Validator) jp.getTarget();
        object.validator();
    }
    @Pointcut("@annotation(Validation)")
    public void valditionAnnotation() {
    }
}
```

Using annotation as `public TrackingId createNewOrder(@Validation Order newOrder)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called before any method that has argument annotated with `@Validation`, I think that's what you wanted:

```java
@Before("execution(* *(.., @Validation (*), ..)) && args(.., toVerify)")
public void validate(final JoinPoint joinPoint, final Object toVerify) {

}
```

If you don't want the parameter value then just remove the `&& ...` part and method argument.

```java
@Before("execution(* *(.., @Validation (*), ..)) && args(.., toVerify)")
  |          |     | |  |     |         |   |    |   |    |      |
  1          2     3 4  5     6         7   8    9   10   11     12
```

1. advice called **before** a join point
2. matching method **execution** join point
3. **method visibility**, matching any (public, private etc.)
4. **method name**, matching any
5. in case your argument is not the only one, it can be between other arguments (not annotated with `@Validation`)
6. **the annotation** you are looking for
7. types of **arguments to the annotation**
8. see 5.
9. to **combine expressions**
10. **making the argument available** to your method
11. as in 5 and 8, it may not be the first argument
12. **name of the argument**, same as in method signature (`Object toVerify`)

Be careful if you have methods with multiple parameters, some annotated, some not, and other combinations - not sure it's gonna always work.

Comment: Can You explain this magic "execution(* *(.., @Validation (*), ..)) && args(.., toVerify)". it work like charm?

Comment: Added explanation in the answer